# angular chart is not visible even though it's there in the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart, angular-chartist.js

I am working with `angular-chart.js` and it's not visible in my page, I have put the charts in the directive.

Code I used:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cold-md-12">
        <canvas class="chart chart-line"
                chart-data="data"
                chart-labels="labels"
                chart-series="series"
                chart-options="options"
                chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"
                chart-click="onClick"
                style="display:block;width:500px;height:400px;">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```js
app.controller('detailsController',['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
      ];

    $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];

    $scope.options = {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              id: 'y-axis-1',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'left'
            },
            {
              id: 'y-axis-2',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'right'
            }
          ]
        }
      };
}]);
```

The controller was placed correctly and the developer tools are not showing any error, also I get the element only problem is the visibility of the map.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with the following,

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"])


.controller("ChartCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.moisture = {heading:"Moisture"};
    $scope.ph = {heading:"Ph Level"};
    $scope.tempreture = {heading:"Soil Temp"};
    $scope.water = {heading:"Environment"};

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
      ];

    $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];

    $scope.options = {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              id: 'y-axis-1',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'left'
            },
            {
              id: 'y-axis-2',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'right'
            }
          ]
        }
      };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>radar Chart</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ChartCtrl" style="width:360px">
       <canvas class="chart chart-bar"  chart-click="onClick" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"  ></canvas>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine. Since you have not provided the complete code with the issues, I can only guess.

- Did you include `'chart.js'` in the module dependencies (`angular.module('chartDemo', ['chart.js'])`).
- Did you include all the libraries needed.

Please find below a JSFiddle for the same. Let me know if the issue persists, also please replicate the issue using the provided JSFiddle and share back!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: the above answer is also same

Comment: @faceturn Say what you want. I typed the same thing. I was including explanation, that's why it was posted late!

Comment: @Charles Does this answer help you?

Answer (score -1):

Update the plugins

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/d6T8TpXJiKpXplJrsOAS?p=preview

Be carefull about the angular-chart.min.js file.